# Post & Page with same slug

Tags: url-rewriting, slug

I've got a post and a page with this slug: `signatures-for-office-365` That's right, the same slug for a post and page.

**Permalinks settings are:** `/news/%postname%/`

When the post URL is requested, wp takes them to the page instead, like so:

**Requested:**`/news/signatures-for-office-365`

**Result:**`/signatures-for-office-365`

I've tried this:

```
add_action('init', function () {
 add_rewrite_rule('news/signatures-for-office-365/?$','index.php?name=signatures-for-office-365', 'top');
}, 1000);
```

I've tried this:

```
add_action('init', function () {
 add_rewrite_rule('news/signatures-for-office-365/?$','index.php?post_type=post&postid=17508', 'top');
}, 1000);
```

Both of which gives the URL I want, but the page displays the blog home instead. Outside of changing the slug to the post, any solutions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior with a new install and default theme, verify that it's not a plugin or your theme causing this.

Comment: You might be onto something because this wasn't a problem for me with a local dev copy of the site. I'll see if I can check it out.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to fix this is to edit either the post or page, then change the permalink on the post/page to something unique.